# Relative Paths From Partials Referencing Other Partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, erb, relative-path, partial

I am using a (primary) partial:

```
<%= render partial: 'shared/page/head' %>
```

Which makes use of other (secondary) partials:

```
<head>
  <%= render partial: 'shared/page/head/title' %>
  <%= render partial: 'shared/page/head/meta' %>
  ...
  <%= render partial: 'shared/page/head/fonts' %>
  ...
  <%= render partial: 'shared/page/head/google_analytics' %>
</head>
```

As you can see I'm currently using paths relative to `app/view` for these secondary partials even though they are sitting in the same directory as the primary partial.

I've tried using relative paths:

```
<%= render partial: 'title' %>
```

Or

```
<%= render partial: './title' %>
```

But neither work.

**Is there a way to have a partial resolve partials it uses using a relative path?**

Comment: Please list the actual paths to your partials

Comment: If you think about your first partial inclusion, that inclusion doesn't 'reset' the working folder of the view being built. If the view being rendered is app/views/projects/show.erb, the "render partial: 'shared/page/head'" is just "go grab the contents of that file, then render it here" - you're still in the app/views/projects folder.

Answer (score 3):

This might be one solution to your problem: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/prepend_view_path

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12973 here is some more explanation on how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I write a helper method to implement it. Sound like work perfectly.

```
def render_relative_partial(relative_path, option={})
    caller_path = caller[0].split(".")[0].split("/")[0..-2].join("/")
  path = caller_path.gsub("#{Rails.root.to_s}/app/views/","") + "/#{relative_path}"

  option[:partial] = path
  render option
end
```

Comment: Nice solution! Very frustrating its not built in. For me I made a little adjustment and changed the last two lines with `render partial: path, locals: option `

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by another poster, [`prepend_view_path`](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActionView/ViewPaths/prepend_view_path) can be used to achieve this.

Here is how to implement it:

`controllers/shared_page_controller.rb`

```rb
class SharedPageController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_view_paths

  # ... 

  private

  def set_view_paths
    prepend_view_path 'app/views/shared/page/head'
  end
end
```

`views/shared/page/head.html.erb`

```rb
<head>
  <%# This will try to find the partial `views/shared/page/head/title.html.erb` %>
  <%= render partial: 'title' %>
  <%= render partial: 'meta' %>
  <%# ... %>
  <%= render partial: 'fonts' %>
  <%# ... %>
  <%= render partial: 'google_analytics' %>
</head>
```

Now Rails will not only look for partials in `app/views`, but also `app/views/shared/page/head`.

Comment: If you're here in 2023, this one worked for me. However I had to use an '/' at the beginning of the partial name in the view. Instead of `render partial: 'title'` I had to use `render partial: '/title'`